# MYSQL php Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting this error and can't figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

The sql - `"INSERT INTO practices (order,name,url) VALUES ('1','Business & Corporate Law','business-corporate-law')"`

Error: `1064You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order,name,url) VALUES ('1','Business & Corporate Law','business-corporate-law')' at line 1`

Here is the php:

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$cols.") VALUES (".$vals.")";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result){die('Error: ' . mysql_errno() . mysql_error());}
```

with $table as "practices"
with $cols as "order,name,url"
with $vals as "'1','Business & Corporate Law','business-corporate-law'"

Comment: please reevaluate your question. Include db schema and update/insert code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order`is a keyword within SQL, so if you use it as a column name (or identifier in general) you have to wrap it like the following:

```
INSERT INTO practices ( `order`, `name`, `url` ) 
  VALUES ('1','Business & Corporate Law','business-corporate-law')
```